Why perf starts to multiplex events even if there are more counters than events?
I was reading about event multiplexing in perf. In my understanding, multiplexing only happens when there is more events than counters. However, tracking the following 3 events already causes multiplexing:
$ perf stat -e LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores apt update

Performance counter stats for 'apt update':

           307,753      LLC-loads                                                     (68.67%)
            58,466      LLC-load-misses           #   19.00% of all LL-cache accesses  (67.31%)
            92,260      LLC-stores                                                    (67.06%)

While cpuid says my CPU has 8 counters:
$ cpuid -1 | grep "number of counters per logical processor"

    number of counters per logical processor = 0x8 (8)

I guess these LLC-related events must be contending for some other counters that CPU only has 2 of them, but I did not seem to find a source for that.
